# Second socket connection in app

Tags: android

I have a chat app and I am creating socket connection for send/receive messages.But now I need one more socket connection.I am curious about battery.If I establish second socket connection,what will be effect to battery ? I need an idea.

Answer (score 0):

basically battery usage is the greatest when you have an active connection (measured by radio in/out). if you are already using one active socket, which is active, i believe that creating another one will not change much.

Comment: How can be sure do you have an idea ?

Comment: That's the theory, you will have to test it.